# Jquery ajax alert not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am trying to pass 2 input values from one page using ajax and if its success then it will alert something else if error it will alert **error**.When i running either in google chrome or in mozilla firefox,I didnt get any error in console.So I thought that there is no error in but Alert is not coming.neither alerting error also.This is the jsffidle for the html part
Following lines are there in html page in head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P6vhG/

this is the jsp code

```
<%!String number,message; %>
<%
number=request.getParameter("toNumber");
message=request.getParameter("body");
out.println(number+"    "+message);




%>
```

Please provide a solution for this.

this is the complete JSP code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Twilio Messages (Send message Example)</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script >



        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#openAlert').click(function(){
alert("hi");
            var number = $('#number').val(); // If its a text input could use .text()
            var msg = $('#body').val(); //If its a text input could use .text()
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "messageSending.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                    data: { toNumber: number, body: msg}
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        alert(data);                  
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
        });
    });
        </script>

</head>
<body><span id="res"></span>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <h2>Twilio Messages (Send message Example)</h2>
                <form class="form-signin" action="#" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span3">
                            Enter Number to send:
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            <input type="text" name="toNumber" id="number" maxlength="13" placeholder="Enter 10 digits number to send" value="+917676462182"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6">
                            <div class="alert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                The number to send an SMS to. This field accepts formatted and unformatted US numbers, e.g. +14155551212, (415) 555-1212 or 415-555-1212.<hr />
                                To send message from SandBox Account. The Number has to be <a href="https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified" target="_blank">verified</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span3">
                            Enter Message to send:
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            <textarea name="body" maxlength="160" placeholder="Enter message to send" id="body">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6">
                            <div class="alert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                The text of the message you want to send, limited to 160 characters.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span9">
                            <button class="btn" type="submit" id="openAlert" >Send</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


 <div id="le-alert" class="alert alert-warn alert-block fade">
      <button href="#" type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
      <h4>Successful</h4>
      <p>Message sent successfully</p>
    </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

this is the complete messageSending.jsp code

```
<%@ page import="com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException" %>
<%@ page import="sms.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%!String number,message; %>
<%
number=request.getParameter("toNumber");
message=request.getParameter("body");
out.println(number+"    "+message);



%>
```

Comment: @user2310289 I have added these lines in head tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: @user2310289 yes its possible.Please tell me my html page conatining ajax and the jsp page to which ajax is calling are on the same directory.So what should be the URL

Comment: @user2310289 In the 3rd line in jjavasript code I wrote alert("hi"); even that is also not working

Comment: @user2310289 where are including javascript means?

Comment: @user2310289 actually in the head section I am including the bootstrap.js and jquery.min.js files **<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>**

Comment: your alert is working now please find here http://jsfiddle.net/P6vhG/5/  problem was in your javascript, you are missing comma , after data: { toNumber: number, body: msg}

Comment: a long journey wasn't it

Comment: @user2310289 See alert is showing error that means control goes to **error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert("erro");
                    }**

Comment: @user2310289 do you know how to solve it?control goes to error part

Comment: @m-t can you please tell me a solution regarding yesterdays question about jquery

Comment: @m-t can you come to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was in your javascript, comma missing , after->  `data: { toNumber: number, body: msg}`

working fine after putting comma over there.

Comment: Thanks for providing answer +1

Comment: Actually the control goes to error part,do you know how to solve it

Comment: what's your goal? please explain so i scratch my head!

Comment: see I am passing  number and message to messageSending.jsp. I have method in messageSending.jsp which accepts number and message.So my requirement is how to pass number and message

Comment: sorry! i have tried with .jsp but its not work, actually i dont have much idea about jsp that how to get values and print, but it is possible with messagesending.php to get values over there and print.

Comment: one more thing try to get form values in javascript through, var datastring = $(".form-signin").serialize(); and try alert(datastring);

Comment: can you please tell me a solution to the yesterdays jquery?

Comment: let move this discussion to chat, i already invited you, come over there